# How did a tiny program called "LinuxLive USB Creator" come to gobble 260 Mb on my disk

Tags: windows-10

I have used a  program called  "LinuxLive USB Creator" a few times to create liveUSB linux on Windows. I remember it was only around 5 Mb but when I downloaded and installed this time, I noticed it uses massive place on my disk for that kind a program. Is it normal?

[image]

Comment: Is that screenshot from Programs and Features? Perhaps the size listed there is including any distro image files that were downloaded with the tool...Check the actual location of the program itself in Explorer and see if it's actually taking up that much space.

Comment: @wysiwyg The screenshot from Control Panel> Programs > Programs and Features  on Windows .. By the way I checked out Program Files and saw that there is a folder called " Virtual box" which is around 250 Mb in LinuxLive USB > Tool Folder in Program Files.. Do you know what it is

Comment: @wysiwyg did I install the program without noticing a checked box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/lili-the-pretty-and-easy-to-use-linux-live-usb-creator/), it appears the LinuxLive USB program can include VirtualBox on your USB drive, allowing you to run Linux from within another OS without installing VirtualBox separately:

> A free Windows application that can perhaps give you the best of both worlds is LinuxLive USB Creator (LiLi) which creates a bootable USB Linux, but also can include a **self contained version of VirtualBox which runs directly from the USB drive. This means you don’t need to install or configure VirtualBox at all to run your Live Linux.**

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is a program that allows you to create virtual machines on your computer. For example you can use it to run Linux (or any other OS) in a "window" on your Windows PC:

[image]

I have never used LinuxLive so I can't tell you for sure, but based on the above and the info in your question, there was probably an option to install VirtualBox alongside LinuxLive when you installed the program, allowing you to run Linux "virtually", as described above.